# How do I check the domain name for a Mac?

Tags: macos, domain

I have Macs on a domain and I want to find out what their PC names are. I went to “System Preferences » Sharing” to look at the name, but in some cases it was blank.

Is there another way to check what the PC name is on the Mac?

Comment: which osx version? does [this](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showpost.php?p=182042&postcount=6) help?

Comment: Are you talking about an Microsoft/Windows Active Directory domain, or an Internet DNS domain?

Answer (score 8):

From the OS X GUI, one way to check the name this system is using on a Microsoft/Windows Active Directory domain is to run the Directory Utility and check the Active Directory settings.

1. Open `/System/Library/CoreServices/Directory\ Utility.app`.

   You can navigate there in the Finder and double-click on it, or open it by typing…

   ```
   open -a Directory\ Utility.app
   ```

   …in a Terminal window.
2. Click on the lock icon and authenticate.
3. Double-click on "Active Directory".
4. Look at the contents of the "Computer ID:" field.

Note that Macs do not have a fully unified host name infrastructure. The name a Mac uses via local multicast Bonjour could be different from the DNS names for its various IP addresses, which could be different from the name it uses for Active Directory.

Comment: Isn't that the same as shown under the Sharing preferences, or can it be a different one?

Comment: @slhck There's no guarantee that it'll be the same.

Answer (score 6):

The question title and the question itself seem to be asking two different questions.

#### Domain Name

To find the domain name on macOS devices, you can try `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and look for a line like `domain example.net`.

You could also try `scutil --dns` and look for lines like `search domain[0] : example.net`.

Perhaps a more "official" way to check domain name is by using the GUI and going to `System Preferences > Network > [Select Active Network Adapter/Connection] > Advanced... > DNS` and then look under the **Search Domains** section.

#### Host Name

To find the "PC name" of the Mac device itself, or the hostname, you could simply run the `hostname` command.

You could also try the command `networksetup -getcomputername`. May or may not require `sudo` (I didn't need to use `sudo` but others online seem to).